# Mounting a single hard drive from mirror raid

Tags: linux, mount, data-recovery, raid

Following issue:
My fathers data server has some hardware issues (most likely the motherboard, it wont start anymore). So I tried to get to the files by removing one of the hdds from the server and mount it to a portable linux machine as one would mount a external hard drive. mount is throwing the error `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock`

When i check the hard drive with `parted -l` it tells me its a GPT partition and unknown files system. The two hard drives where configured in a mirror raid where the linux that handled that raid was installed on those hard drives. So the file system is most likely a ext3. I tried that on the mount command to no avail, same error.

After some research i stumbled upon several ways to (re)assemble the raid but all of those solutions did not respect the fact that it could be a GPT partition.

The used Linux distribution was Ubuntu, I dont have a version info for that sadly. It was also used to handle the network traffic (bastion setup) and as VPN server.

output of `parted /dev/sde/ unit MiB print`:

```
Error: /dev/sde: unrecognised disk label
Model: WDC WD10 02F9YZ-09H1JL1 (scsi)                                     
Disk /dev/sde: 953870MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sde/`

```
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sde
```

Now to my question(s)

- Can i use said assemble methods (i.e [this one](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/05/08/how-to-mount-software-raid1-member-using-mdadm/)) anyway?
- Can any of this cause a loss of data (his whole office work of the last decade are saved on there)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_his whole office work of the last decade are saved on there_" the best thing you can do after attempting this recovery is to insist on a proper regular automated backup. There is no excuse for not having a backup these days.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to identify the Linux distribution used on the server, as this can help identify the type of filesystem you need to consider. Please also identify the Linux distribution on your portable system

Comment: he did have one but since he thought of retiring soon(ish) he cancelled it... So basically the work from the last year is not saved other than on that raid drive

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it's GPT or not. The partitions should still show as, well, partitions if the kernel recognizes them. Run `mdadm --examine /dev/sdx1`, it'll tell you if it's part of an mdadm array. Then you can run something like `mdadm --assemble --readonly --run /dev/md9 /dev/sdx1` to start it.

Comment: Added the two requested command outputs. Could it be an issue that i connected the hard drive via external SATA to USB adapter? Should i connect it internally?

Comment: I would say that it looks like you've been using hardware RAID, and this particular implementation isn't understood by `mdadm`. If that's the case your only option at this point is to find another motherboard that supports the same RAID format and hope it will read the disk for you without formatting it. Unfortunately this is why you should have backups.